# Centering grid of objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

As in the title, im trying to create a grid of objects in P5 `Spot(x, y, size)`, with a 4 pixel space between them and center it on the canvas without using `translate`, heres what i've got:

```js
  gridSize = 7;
  spotSize = 60;
  spots = [];

  for (var y = height / 2 - ((gridSize * spotSize + gridSize * 4) / 2); y < (height / 2 - ((gridSize * spotSize + gridSize * 4) / 2)) + (gridSize * spotSize + gridSize * 4); y += spotSize + 4) {

    for (var x = width / 2 - ((gridSize * spotSize + gridSize * 4) / 2); x < (width / 2 - ((gridSize * spotSize + gridSize * 4) / 2)) + (gridSize * spotSize + gridSize * 4); x += spotSize + 4) {

      spots.push(new Spot(x, y, spotSize));

    }
  }
```

Problem is that my grid looks off, why is it not centered? Probably a really simple and stupid mistake but i cant find it. Any help appreciated.

My Spot object just draws an ellipse at the given x and y. Entire code at http://codepen.io/felipe_mare/pen/GWyMOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-SOLVED-

```
spots.push(new Spot(x + spotSize/2, y + spotSize/2, spotSize));
```

Wasn't taking into account the fact that the ellipse is drawn from the center, so i have to add the radius of the circle `spotSize/2`